# iOS - Animation - Image coming out of circle

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage, uiviewanimation

I have a situation where I want an animation that look like image is coming/pop out from the object or another image having a circle. I know how to make image that coming out of rect but here I have a circle. Situation is like, someone pops out of window or say chick/bird coming out of egg.

Any help or suggestion or direction would be highly appreciable.

Thanks.

Edit: Here I attach the image, egg is background, when I tap/touch a egg, boy coming out of the egg with animations.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what effect you are trying to achieve. Could you explain in more detail or provide a image of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hi David, I edited the question with image. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have three different images for the above example:

- One for the back (inside) of the egg
- One for the guy coming out of the egg
- One for the front (outside) of the egg

Then you would put all three images in that order (bottom to top) so that the part of the guy that is behind the third image is hidden. Then you simple animate the position of the guy image up to make it look like he is popping out of the egg.

Comment: but the thing is, I have a planet of eggs and they all are of different size.

Comment: The alternative is knowing the path that should be used to mask each image to the jagged edge but that would probably be more complex and require more work

Comment: Thanks David, May be I should use the mask around image path.